# Performing POST method Using Axios and Pipe Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, axios, pipeline

So I am currently learning about FP and the use of the `Pipe` operator which combines `n` functions and simply calls it from left to right. Currently, I am trying to make a POST call using Axios and then handle the data returned appropriately, but then the `pending` promise value always results to `undefined`. Here is what my code looks like.

The pipe function

```
const pipe = (...fns) => (initValue) => fns.reduce((v, f) => f(v), initValue)
```

Here is the first function that is passed to the pipe function

```
const dataToPost = ({ title, body, userId }) => {
  return {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    data: {
      title,
      body,
      userId,
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  }
}
```

Here is how I implement the pipe function passing it the various arguments

```
const postTodoFunc = ({ pipe }) => {
  return async function postTodo({ title, body, userId }) {
    const callJSONAPI = pipe(dataToPost, axios, output) ///this line here

    const calledFunc = await callJSONAPI({
      title,
      body,
      userId,
    })
    return calledFunc
  }
}
```

The `output` function looks like this.

```
const output = (response) => {
  return response.data
}
```

The `postTodoFunc` is invoked like this

```
const postedTodo = postTodoFunc({ pipe })
const result = postedTodo({
  title: 'Rule the world',
  body: 'some random body',
  userId: 1,
})

console.log(result) // undefined
```

Now from my understanding, the `dataToPost` function is called first which returns an object that is equivalent to this

```
{
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    data: {
      title,
      body,
      userId,
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  }
```

This object is then passed to `axios` which is then equivalent to the following format

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    data: {
      title,
      body,
      userId,
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  })
```

The response from this `axios` call returns `undefined`. Because I thought the response will be passed to the next function which is this case `output` function. But that does not seem to be the case. How can I fix this and get the correct data? Initially from the JSONPlaceholder website, the response is meant to be like this

```
{
  id: 101,
  title: 'Rule the world',
  body: 'Some random body',
  userId: 1
}
```

but then again, I am getting `undefined` after the pending promise.

Comment: The problem you have here is that you're piping asynchronous functions. These don't behave the same as synchronous ones. Async stuff gets deferred until all the sync code has finished running. So when you "return" the async axios call, it doesn't return the axios call's response value (even though you're awaiting it) it returns the actual Promise itself. And so in your `output` function you're trying to access the `.data` value of the Promise object, which is obviously undefined. Print out `response` and see.

Comment: Have a look at this for an example of chaining/piping functions which are asynchronous: https://itnext.io/roll-your-own-async-compose-pipe-functions-658cafe4c46f or Google around for other posts/articles about the topic

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks, I'll check it out. @Jayce444